# How to print intermediate tensor's value in some function in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook

When using tensorflow, how to print some intermediate tensor's value in some function? For example:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

def f(X):
    tf.set_random_seed(1) 
    W1 = tf.get_variable('W1',[4, 4, 3, 8], initializer = tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer(seed = 0))
    Z1 = tf.nn.conv2d(X,W1, strides = [1,1,1,1], padding = 'SAME')
    return Z1

with tf.Session() as sess:
    np.random.seed(1)
    X=tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 64, 64, 3])
    Z1 = f(X)
    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    sess.run(init)
    a = sess.run(Z1, {X: np.random.randn(2,64,64,3)})
    print("Z1 = " + str(a))
```

How to print the concrete values of tensor `W1`, `X` when compute `Z1`? I need the values of `W1` and `X` to debug.

PS: I'm using **Jupyter Notebook**, TensorFlow 1.15

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's three ways.

### Changing the arguments of your method

```
def f(X):
    tf.set_random_seed(1) 
    W1 = tf.get_variable('W1',[4, 4, 3, 8], initializer = tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer(seed = 0))
    Z1 = tf.nn.conv2d(X,W1, strides = [1,1,1,1], padding = 'SAME')    
    return Z1, W1

with tf.Session() as sess:
    np.random.seed(1)
    X=tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 64, 64, 3])
    W1, Z1 = f(X)
    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    sess.run(init)    

    w, x, a = sess.run([W1, X, Z1], {X: np.random.randn(2,64,64,3)})
    print("Z1 = " + str(a))
    print('W = ', w)
    print('X = ', x)
```

### Without changing the arguments of your method

```
...
    X=tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 64, 64, 3])
    Z1 = f(X)
    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    sess.run(init)    
    with tf.variable_scope('',reuse=True) as scope:
      W1 = tf.get_variable('W1')
    w, x, a = sess.run([W1, X, Z1], {X: np.random.randn(2,64,64,3)})
    print("Z1 = " + str(a))
    print('W = ', w)
    print('X = ', x)
```

Or you can use eager execution instead of graph execution. I think this would be the best way to use TF for debugging as printing/debugging values with Graph execution is clunky.

Answer (score 0):

In tensorflow1.x, one way I know is use `tf.enable_eager_execution`, enable eager model, then you can use `tf.tensor` just like numpy.